# Приложение не замечает тап по кнопке

Tags: android, kotlin, android-on-click, onclicklistener, setonclicklistener

Приложение не замечает тап по кнопке `addToCard`, при том, что setOnClickListener работают во всех случаях (проверял во время дебага), остальные кнопки работают корректно

```
class AddHolder(val bind: AddClothingItemBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(bind.root) {
    
            private val binding : AddClothingItemBinding = bind
    
            fun bind(addLocalModel: AddLocalModel, addToCard: (AddLocalModel) -> Unit,
                     moreCount: (AddLocalModel) -> Unit, lessCount: (AddLocalModel) -> Unit){
                // получаем ссылку на изображение
                val getImage = addLocalModel.image
                // получаем изображение, которое находится по ссылке и добавляем его в imageMedications
                Picasso.get().load(getImage).into(binding.imageClothes)
                binding.nameClothes.text = addLocalModel.name
                binding.descriptionClothes.text = addLocalModel.description
                binding.discountClothes.text = addLocalModel.discount
                binding.priceClothes.text = addLocalModel.price
                binding.sizeClothes.text = addLocalModel.size
    
                binding.addToCard.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
    
                    addToCard(addLocalModel) // вот этот метод не запускается
    
                })
    
                binding.moreProductBasket.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                    moreCount(addLocalModel) 
    
                    addToCard(addLocalModel)
    
                })
    
                binding.lessProductBasket.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                    lessCount(addLocalModel) 
    
                })
            }
    
        }
```

Разметка item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/cardClothes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/black"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:checkable="true">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageClothes"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/nameClothes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageClothes"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/descriptionClothes"
                android:layout_width="240dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/nameClothes"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageClothes"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/discountClothes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/descriptionClothes"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageClothes"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/lessProductBasket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/discountClothes"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/imageClothes"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/less"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/sizeClothes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/discountClothes"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/lessProductBasket"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="hp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/moreProductBasket"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/discountClothes"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/sizeClothes"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/more"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/priceClothes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/curr"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/curr"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin = "10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:text="@string/ruble"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addToCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/card"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backg_button"/>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/removeFromCard"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:src="@drawable/delete"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/backg_button"/>



        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</layout>
```

Comment: Попробуй вызвать лямбду так: addToCard.invoke(addLocalModel)

Comment: @Circassian, не сработало. Забыл сказать, когда я вставляю метод addToCard(addLocalModel) в другой setOnClickListener, к примеру binding.moreProductBasket.setOnClickListener, вызыв этого метода в binding.moreProductBasket.setOnClickListener происходит

Comment: @Circassian, а внутри  binding.addToCard.setOnClickListener, не происходит выхов никаких методов (я, ради экасперимента, попробовал поместить туда также метод lessCount(addLocalModel))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, я сделал кнопку удаления (функциональность которой ещё не прописал) поверх кнопки добавления.